# Loading Angular8 build files using require js

Tags: javascript, angular, angular8, require

Is there any way to load Angular8 build files using RequireJS? I tried the below syntax and it's not working. Confusing thing is that there was no error in the console either.

```
require(['runtime.js'],function() {
 require(['polyfills.js'], function() {
  require(['scripts.js'], function() {
   require(['main.js'])
   })
  })
})
```

Comment: Could please specify why do you need this?

Comment: Does require calls are really weird. Can you show your require JS configuration As well as the portion of your index. HTML where do you load RequireJS?  In Broad terms, Yes, you can load any JavaScript file with RequireJS.